# iOS SIGABRT on launch

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt, crashlytics

I recently setted up Crashlytics to receive crashlogs from my iOS app and I keep on getting a SIGABRT crashlog and i can't find from where it comes from.

Here's the crashlog if you can help me a little:

```
Exception Type: SIGABRT Code: ABORT at 0x364b132c
com.apple.main-thread Crashed
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
     libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_kill + 54
     libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 94
     libc++abi.dylib     abort_message + 46
     libc++abi.dylib     safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 120
     libc++abi.dylib     operator delete(void*)
     libc++abi.dylib     __cxa_current_exception_type
     libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_rethrow + 12
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 136
     UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1080
     MyApplication   main.m line 16 main
com.apple.libdispatch-manager
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  kevent + 24
     libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 714
     libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_mgr_wakeup
WebThread
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_mutexwait + 24
     libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_mutex_lock + 382
     WebCore     _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 214
     WebCore     WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 30
     CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 258
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 952
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     WebCore     RunWebThread(void*) + 402
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 56
     MyApplication   CLSMachExceptionServer + 120
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 56
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 882
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     Foundation  +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
     Foundation  -[NSThread main] + 72
     Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 1048
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
Thread
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait + 24
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_cond_wait + 640
     libsystem_c.dylib   pthread_cond_wait + 40
     Foundation  -[NSCondition wait] + 196
     MyApplication  PFCommandCache.m line 496 -[PFCommandCache runLoop]
     Foundation  -[NSThread main] + 72
     Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 1048
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
Thread
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 56
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 882
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     Foundation  -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 256
     Foundation  -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 78
     MyApplication  PF_AFURLConnectionOperation.m line 151 +[PF_AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:]
     Foundation  -[NSThread main] + 72
     Foundation  __NSThread__main__ + 1048
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
com.apple.CFSocket.private
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __select + 20
     CoreFoundation  __CFSocketManager + 732
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
Thread
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __workq_kernreturn + 8
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 616
WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_trap + 20
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg + 56
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
     CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 882
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
     CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
     WebCore     WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 128
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_start + 320
Thread
     libsystem_kernel.dylib  __workq_kernreturn + 8
     libsystem_c.dylib   _pthread_wqthread + 616
Thread
     libsystem_c.dylib   start_wqthread
```

Thanks for your help !

EDIT: Just to be clear, i received this crashlog multiple times, I wasn't able to reproduce the bug on my testing devices

Comment: type bt(backtrace) on debugger console when app crashes, it might help in finding the problem.

Comment: Yes but i can't reproduce the bug on my testing devices..

Comment: I sometimes get this when I change the bundle Id and the application with the old bundle id was present on the device. When I try to launch the same application with the new bundle id, either it launches the old one, or it crashes with a similar error message. What I usually do is delete the application (old and new application) and restart XCode and the Simulator.

Comment: This trace shows you're re-throwing an exception, so isn't particularly useful. Do you get any information about the original exception from Crashlytics?

Comment: No, just `Exception Type: SIGABRT Code: ABORT at 0x364b132c`

Comment: Are you using the C++ operator `delete` somewhere? It seems like you're trying to delete an object you can't...

Comment: change Crashlytics library type from "Required" to "Weak" in target.. this may help you..Just give try..

Comment: Sanjit: No, i don't use it anywhere in my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are removing/deleting something in your applicationDelegate (applicationDidEnterBackground etc.) within your WebThread(UIWebView?) thats not there anymore if you close/reopen your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing print object on that hex code, sometimes can provide some insight.

```
po 0x364b132c
```

Would have left this as a comment, but for some reason can't comment on your post.

Comment: I may have been unclear, i can't reproduce the bug on my testing devices, this is a crashlog that i receive. Printing the object at memory adress `0x364b132c` won't return the same thing each time..

Comment: Oh, I missed the Crashlytics bit.  Sorry about that.